# Replacement needed for document.ready when loading a page into a div (used a jquery-ui Dialog)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm creating a div with jquery, loading content from webserver with load, and then dynamically creating a dialog using jquery-ui.  This is working great, however, in the page that is loaded there is $(document).ready code that is supposed to fire when the page is loaded.  Currently it fires instantly, even though the page isn't loaded.  Currently the only way I can get the page to load properly is move the code in the document.ready to a setTimeout (this seems sketchy to me and is probably going to cause race conditions galore).   The following is the code that creates the dialog (if my rambling description above wasn't too clear):

```
function AddWindow(url, windowName, windowTitle)
{
   $('<div id="' + windowName + '"/>').load(url,function()
   {
     $(this).dialog({title: windowTitle, modal: true}).bind('dialogclose', 
       function () { $(this).remove(); });
   });
}
```

Note: This code opens dozens of different pages, with different code that has to be run upon loading so I can't bind to 'dialogopen', it has to be javascript on the page that has loaded.  And yes I have tried using body.onload on the page but it fails too.

EDIT:  People have asked for the code that loads on the page, unfortunately there are dozens of examples of what loads, but for example, on one page we have to create tabs.  However when this is called $('.tabs') returns []:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.tabs').tabs("div.panes > div", {effect: 'ajax', api: true});
  });
```

what I have been forced to do is add this to the page:

```
  setTimeout(function() {
     $('.tabs').tabs("div.panes > div", {effect: 'ajax', api: true});
  }, 50);
```

Comment: Can you should the code on the loaded pages, the code that contains the $(document).ready() ?

Comment: where is ur code **with** the doc ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just simply listen to the dialogopen elements matching your content?

```
$('#windowName or .tabs.parent(), not the whole document').bind('dialogopen', function() {
   $('.tabs').tabs("div.panes > div", {effect: 'ajax', api: true});
});
```

Or did you try using a custom event?

```
function AddWindow(url, windowName, windowTitle)
{
   $('<div id="' + windowName + '"/>').load(url,function()
   {
     $(this).dialog({title: windowTitle, modal: true}).bind('dialogclose', function () { $(this).remove(); })
       .trigger( "myDialogReady" );
   });
}
```

and

```
$('#windowName').bind("myDialogReady",function(){
    $('.tabs').tabs("div.panes > div", {effect: 'ajax', api: true});
});
```

Comment: This is a great idea, however, the problem is that the AddWindow function creates the windowName div (see the $('<div id="' + windowName + '"/>') part of the code), and thus when the code runs it can't be bound to since it isn't in the dom yet (it is in the shadow land of elements created dynimcally by jQuery).  What I really need is a way to globally bind to the dialogopen event and then check the id of the window being opened....

Comment: Did you try `.live()` / `.delegate()` ?

Answer (score 0):

document.ready fires when the DOM is ready for manipulation.
If you want to know when your page was fully loaded, try using window.load instead :

```js
$(window).load(function() {
 alert("images are loaded!");
});
```

Comment: This does not work, this event never fires.  The page is already loaded, I am loading new pages into divs.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check if it exists, and if not, create it?

```
if ($("#" + windowName).length==0)
{
    $(document.body).append("<div id='" + windowName + '" />");
}
// YOUR CODE...
```

Comment: Not quite what I want to do.  The code is create modal dialog boxes that have their content loaded from the server.  The dialog boxes get loaded at different times, testing to see if it exists does not help.